# Como limito el input a si o no?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que se pregunta si se quiere seguir jugando y hay que contestar S o N, pero no se muy bien como limitar para que si pones otra cosa no te lo acepte, ahora adjunto el siguiente codigo (no es el código completo ya que solo necesito ayuda para limitar el input a si o no).

```
resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)")
while not resp=="S" or not resp=="N":
    print("Tienes que escribir S o N")
    resp=input("¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)")
```

Porque no funciona este código y me devuelve esta respuesta??

```
¿Que número eliges?30
Este número es un multiplo de 2
Este número es un multiplo de 3
Este número es un multiplo de 5
¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)N
Tienes que escribir S o N
¿Quieres seguir jugando? (S/N)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mejor utiliza esta comparación:

```
while not (resp == 'S' or resp == 'N'):
```

Lo que estabas haciendo era que continuase si era distinto a S, o era distinto a N... entonces si ponías N, era distinto a S, por lo tanto continuaba, y viceversa.

En cambio con la comparación de arriba, dices que continúe si no es S o N.

Comment: `while resp not in "SsNn":`

Comment: También hubiera valido con cambiar el `or` por `and`:  `while not resp=="S" and not resp=="N":`

Comment: @CandidMoe con tu código, si le doy un input vacío se lo come, por ejemplo si le doy al Enter sin haber escrito nada.

Comment: Vale, pero la práctica normal es tomar Enter como la alternativa por default, que podría ser S o N, según el caso. Así el ingreso es más rápido.